# ActionBar has correct colors in Android 4.2, wrong colors in Android 2.3

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-holo-everywhere

I'm using ActionBarSherlock and HoloEverywhere in my app.  I used the ActionBar Style Generator to generate my styles and then modified them a bit by hand for text colors, etc.

I'm having a problem where my ActionBar looks correct on my Android 4.2 device (that is, orange with white text), but on my Android 2.3 device the ActionBar is black with grey text.

Does anyone know what might cause this?

[image]

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="@style/Holo.Theme.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.MyApp</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item> -->
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.MyApp.NavigationDropDownStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.MyApp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.MyApp.TitleTextStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.MyApp.NavigationDropDownStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/ActionBar.Solid.MyApp.NavigationDropDownStyle.TextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.MyApp.NavigationDropDownStyle.TextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.MyApp.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item> -->
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.MyApp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.MyApp</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.MyApp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_MyApp</item> 
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.MyApp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_MyApp</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.MyApp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_MyApp</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.MyApp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_MyApp</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.MyApp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_MyApp</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.MyApp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_MyApp</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.MyApp.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.MyApp</item>
</style>
```

--------------- EDIT ----------------------

[image]

So I'm now having a problem where the action bar is taking up the entire screen on the Android 2.3 device (but works fine on Android 4.2).  Do I need to remove the "android:" from the parent attributes?

parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow"

When I tried this, Eclipse was unable to find the theme.

```
 <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="@style/Holo.Theme.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.MyApp</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item> -->
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.MyApp.NavigationDropDownStyle</item>

    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_MyApp</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.MyApp</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.MyApp</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.MyApp</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.MyApp</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.MyApp</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_MyApp</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_MyApp</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.MyApp</item>
    <!-- <item name="textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item> -->
    <item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.MyApp.NavigationDropDownStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.MyApp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.MyApp.TitleTextStyle</item>

    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_MyApp</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_MyApp</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_MyApp</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.MyApp</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.MyApp.TitleTextStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.MyApp.NavigationDropDownStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/ActionBar.Solid.MyApp.NavigationDropDownStyle.TextStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.MyApp.NavigationDropDownStyle.TextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>

</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.MyApp.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>

    <!-- <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item> -->
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.MyApp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.MyApp</item>

    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_MyApp</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.MyApp</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.MyApp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_MyApp</item> 

</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.MyApp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_MyApp</item>

</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.MyApp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_MyApp</item>

    <item name="background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_MyApp</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.MyApp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_MyApp</item>

    <item name="background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_MyApp</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.MyApp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_MyApp</item>

</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.MyApp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_MyApp</item>

    <item name="background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_MyApp</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [official docs](http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html), you need to also declare the attributes without the `android:` namespace. In your case, those attributes are only getting applied to the native implementation.

Comment: Okay, I tried that, but many of the attributes are not found.  I get the following error on like 10 or 15 items:

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 
 'popupBackground'.

Comment: First, you need to inherit from `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar`, as the docs say. Second, that specific attribute does not come from ABS but has been in the framework all along. Edit: never mind on the theme, that's HoloEverywhere.

Comment: Its my understanding that the HoloEverywhere themes extend from the Sherlock themes, so using those themes should be okay?

Also, can you clarify what you mean by the attribute does not come from ABS, but has been in the framework all along?

I'm getting the error on a lot of the attributes, including simple ones like this:

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 
 'textSize'.

Comment: You only need to mirror resources that ABS defines for compatibility reasons. Things like `textSize` are standard and should have only one copy, with the `android:` prefix. 

You can either look at `abs__attrs.xml` to see what attributes ABS defines or take a look at the API version they were first introduced in - if it's after 10, ABS (or HoloEverywhere) probably defines it as well. 

Apologies for the confusion regarding the theme. It should be okay, I always get `Holo.Theme` (the HoloEverywhere one) and `Theme.Holo` (the official one) confused.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help so far!  I'm still running into a few more problems, so may I ask you a few more questions?  I posted a screenshot of my new problem, along with my updated code in the original post.

Comment: Regarding the parent attributes, you'll need to replace them with whatever the style in HoloEverywhere is. I think you're seeing that bug because the Widget.Holo styles do not exist in the framework, so they get replaced with a default.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up fixing it by changing the parent of the actionbar style to the sherlock actionbar style.